# SSIS Derived Column Rounds Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

One of the columns I am selecting in an SSIS query, `TransTotal`, has values like this:

```
----
4615
3845
8706
8725
4205
----
```

I my derived column, I need to insert a decimal, so I have added this expression:

```
(DT_NUMERIC,10,2)(TransTotal / 100)
```

Expecting the results to look like:

```
-----
46.15
38.45
87.06
87.25
42.05
-----
```

But instead, they look like:

```
-----
46.00
38.00
87.00
87.00
42.00
-----
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `TransTotal` is an `INT`, then your code is currently performing first an integer division (`TransTotal / 100`, meaning that 8725/100 equals 87 because it's an integer) and then converting it to a `NUMERIC`. You need to first convert `TransTotal` to `NUMERIC` and then perform the division:

```
((DT_NUMERIC,10,2) TransTotal) / 100
```